# Oak-D (depthAI) python, 14" Mac M1 silicon Ventura 13.3.1, stuck at runtime error: Cmake not installed. Anyone get past this issue?

Tags: python, cmake, apple-m1, apple-silicon

Got my environment together including the arm64 for m1 silicon mac and the python version:

```
MBP people % python3 -c 'import platform; print(platform.machine())'
arm64
MBP people % curl https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.9.13/python-3.9.13-macos11.pkg --output p3.9.pkg
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 37.0M  100 37.0M    0     0  25.1M      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 25.1M
MBP people % sudo installer -pkg p3.9.pkg -target /
Password:
installer: Package name is Python
installer: Upgrading at base path /
installer: The upgrade was successful.
MBP people % python3 -m pip install depthai
Collecting depthai
  Downloading depthai-2.21.2.0-cp311-cp311-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl (10.0 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 10.0/10.0 MB 19.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Installing collected packages: depthai
Successfully installed depthai-2.21.2.0

[notice] A new release of pip available: 22.3.1 -> 23.1.2
[notice] To update, run: pip3 install --upgrade pip
MBP people % pip3 install --upgrade pip
Requirement already satisfied: pip in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages (22.3.1)
Collecting pip
  Downloading pip-23.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 2.1/2.1 MB 22.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Installing collected packages: pip
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    Found existing installation: pip 22.3.1
    Uninstalling pip-22.3.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-22.3.1
Successfully installed pip-23.1.2
```

then when run requirements, depthai doesn't compile because "CMake isn't installed"

```
MBP people % pip install -r requirements.txt 
Collecting depthai==2.16.0.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Using cached depthai-2.16.0.0.tar.gz (360 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting blobconverter==1.3.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Using cached blobconverter-1.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Collecting opencv-python (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Using cached opencv_python-4.7.0.72-cp37-abi3-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl (32.6 MB)
Collecting numpy (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
  Using cached numpy-1.24.3-cp311-cp311-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl (13.8 MB)
Collecting requests (from blobconverter==1.3.0->-r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Using cached requests-2.29.0-py3-none-any.whl (62 kB)
Collecting PyYAML (from blobconverter==1.3.0->-r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Using cached PyYAML-6.0-cp311-cp311-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl (167 kB)
Collecting boto3 (from blobconverter==1.3.0->-r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Using cached boto3-1.26.125-py3-none-any.whl (135 kB)
Collecting botocore<1.30.0,>=1.29.125 (from boto3->blobconverter==1.3.0->-r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Using cached botocore-1.29.125-py3-none-any.whl (10.7 MB)
Collecting jmespath<2.0.0,>=0.7.1 (from boto3->blobconverter==1.3.0->-r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Using cached jmespath-1.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
Collecting s3transfer<0.7.0,>=0.6.0 (from boto3->blobconverter==1.3.0->-r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Using cached s3transfer-0.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (79 kB)
Collecting charset-normalizer<4,>=2 (from requests->blobconverter==1.3.0->-r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Using cached charset_normalizer-3.1.0-cp311-cp311-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl (121 kB)
Collecting idna<4,>=2.5 (from requests->blobconverter==1.3.0->-r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Using cached idna-3.4-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
Collecting urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 (from requests->blobconverter==1.3.0->-r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Using cached urllib3-1.26.15-py2.py3-none-any.whl (140 kB)
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17 (from requests->blobconverter==1.3.0->-r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Using cached certifi-2022.12.7-py3-none-any.whl (155 kB)
Collecting python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1 (from botocore<1.30.0,>=1.29.125->boto3->blobconverter==1.3.0->-r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Using cached python_dateutil-2.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (247 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /Users/amandaperry/Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages (from python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1->botocore<1.30.0,>=1.29.125->boto3->blobconverter==1.3.0->-r requirements.txt (line 2)) (1.16.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: depthai
  Building wheel for depthai (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for depthai (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [71 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 76, in run
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 466, in check_output
          return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 548, in run
          with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 1024, in __init__
          self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 1901, in _execute_child
          raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
      FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'cmake'
      
      During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
      
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 251, in build_wheel
          return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/61/s0hk59210k1g62cjz2f9brph0000gn/T/pip-build-env-wov_iucu/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 416, in build_wheel
          return self._build_with_temp_dir(['bdist_wheel'], '.whl',
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/61/s0hk59210k1g62cjz2f9brph0000gn/T/pip-build-env-wov_iucu/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 401, in _build_with_temp_dir
          self.run_setup()
        File "/private/var/folders/61/s0hk59210k1g62cjz2f9brph0000gn/T/pip-build-env-wov_iucu/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 488, in run_setup
          self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/61/s0hk59210k1g62cjz2f9brph0000gn/T/pip-build-env-wov_iucu/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 338, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 183, in <module>
        File "/private/var/folders/61/s0hk59210k1g62cjz2f9brph0000gn/T/pip-build-env-wov_iucu/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 107, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/61/s0hk59210k1g62cjz2f9brph0000gn/T/pip-build-env-wov_iucu/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 185, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/61/s0hk59210k1g62cjz2f9brph0000gn/T/pip-build-env-wov_iucu/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 201, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "/private/var/folders/61/s0hk59210k1g62cjz2f9brph0000gn/T/pip-build-env-wov_iucu/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "/private/var/folders/61/s0hk59210k1g62cjz2f9brph0000gn/T/pip-build-env-wov_iucu/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1244, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "/private/var/folders/61/s0hk59210k1g62cjz2f9brph0000gn/T/pip-build-env-wov_iucu/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/private/var/folders/61/s0hk59210k1g62cjz2f9brph0000gn/T/pip-build-env-wov_iucu/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 343, in run
          self.run_command("build")
        File "/private/var/folders/61/s0hk59210k1g62cjz2f9brph0000gn/T/pip-build-env-wov_iucu/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "/private/var/folders/61/s0hk59210k1g62cjz2f9brph0000gn/T/pip-build-env-wov_iucu/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1244, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "/private/var/folders/61/s0hk59210k1g62cjz2f9brph0000gn/T/pip-build-env-wov_iucu/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/private/var/folders/61/s0hk59210k1g62cjz2f9brph0000gn/T/pip-build-env-wov_iucu/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build.py", line 131, in run
          self.run_command(cmd_name)
        File "/private/var/folders/61/s0hk59210k1g62cjz2f9brph0000gn/T/pip-build-env-wov_iucu/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "/private/var/folders/61/s0hk59210k1g62cjz2f9brph0000gn/T/pip-build-env-wov_iucu/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1244, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "/private/var/folders/61/s0hk59210k1g62cjz2f9brph0000gn/T/pip-build-env-wov_iucu/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "<string>", line 78, in run
      RuntimeError: CMake must be installed to build the following extensions: depthai
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for depthai
Failed to build depthai
ERROR: Could not build wheels for depthai, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Followed advice to install CMake on mac by first installing MacPorts for Ventura 13 (which I did) and then `sudo port install cmake`

Still get the error above when running requirements. Having lots of M1 silicon "unicorn" problems of late. Hoping there are others who have found a way past this point. Note: the program runs on my coworkers' computer so there shouldn't be inherent issues with the underlying base code.

Comment: any difference if you restart the shell first after installing CMake / macports? Is CMake in any directory in your `PATH` now?

Comment: I restarted everything again and it got me past that error so far. New error farther along into compiling, so I'll call that a success so far! I'm having to increase my terminal lines in order to find more information on the next error: 

subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', '--build', '.', '--config', 'Release', '--', '-j2']' returned non-zero exit status 2.

Comment: 1) This might have been a case of needing to restart a process like your shell to get it to pick up updates you made at a system level outside of that shell to the system `PATH` environment variable. 2) ask your new question in a new question post. Provide the error message and instructions to reproduce the issue.